# Trying to understand the Peterson's Algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, process

I am trying to understand the Peterson's algorithm and I came across this question. I traced the code and I wrote my observations. Please check my observation, Am I on the right track?

***Question*** from Textbook: Suppose the are only two processes, one with `pid` value 0 and one with `pid` value 1. What is wrong with this concurrency algorithm?

```
  while(True)
    {
     flag[pid] = 1
     turn = 1-pid
     while( flag[1-pid] && turn == 1-pid ); // busy wait

     // critical section
     ...
     // end of critical section

     flag[pid] = 0
    }
```

Tracing the code:

```
    ---------- Process 0: ---------- | ---------- Process 1: ----------
                                     |
    pid = 0                          |    pid = 1
    flag[0] = 1                      |    flag[1] = 1
    turn = 1 - 0 = 1                 |    turn = 1 - 1 = 0
                                     |
    while (flag[1 - 0]               |    while (flag[1 - 1]    
            && turn == (1 - 0))      |            && turn == (1 - 1))
                                     |
    // --> while (flag [1] && true)  |    // --> while (flag [0] && true)
    // --> while (flag [1])          |    // --> while (flag [0])
```

***My observations***

1. I think in the busy waiting sections, both while loops may run
   forever.
2. I also think when one of the processes for example process `0` get out
   of it's while loop then it can set it's flag to `false` (`flag[0] = 0`) and causes the
   other process *Not to run*. Thus, process `0` can run twice and process 1 doesn't run at all. Further, it can also cause the process `1` to starve or vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Peterson's Algorithm** guarantees access to critical sections for both processes without any **starvation**.

- `flag` indicates the desire to enter the `critical section`.
- `turn` is used by a process to allow the other finish waiting and proceed to `critical section`.
- When a process finish it's job at the `critical section` it states it's desire is gone (`flag[pid] = False`). This allows the other one to enter the section. However, if one process, due to context switches, toggles it's `flag` on and off without the other one noticing it, it still has to toggle it's `turn` flag.

### Summary

**Peterson's Algorithm** works because, each process has the following mindset:

`I would like to access the critical section. So, I'll wait my turn`

---

So you see, everything works out **just fine** in the end. There is no **starvation**, each process progresses **without** being **stuck**, and critical section is accessed by **both** processes over and over again.